# Why is Closing Process Group of Project HR management empty?

Tags: project-team, process, human-resources

I am a newbie to Project Management. While going through a course for basic understanding of Project Management, I got stuck with the Closing Process Group of Project HR Management Knowledge Area.

The book says, Executing Process Group for HR Management includes processes to acquire, develop and manage project team however the Closing Process Group contains no activities or processes. Shouldn't it contain the releasing process of the resources?

Tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't it contain the releasing process of the resources?

No. You don't want to **release** your human resources after each project - that would entail firing them.

You simply want to free them up for the next project, so you simply close the process group. The resources are  no longer attached to the old project and can be relocated to another one.